# How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following HTML `<select>` element:

```
<select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode">
  <option value="10">Annual Leave</option>
  <option value="11">Medical Leave</option>
  <option value="14">Long Service</option>
  <option value="17">Leave Without Pay</option>
</select>
```

Using a JavaScript function with the `leaveCode` number as a parameter, how do I select the appropriate option in the list?

Comment: see my answer for a comparison of performance for different methods

Answer (score 777, accepted):

You can use this function:

```js
function selectElement(id, valueToSelect) {    
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.value = valueToSelect;
}

selectElement('leaveCode', '11');
```

```html
<select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode">
  <option value="10">Annual Leave</option>
  <option value="11">Medical Leave</option>
  <option value="14">Long Service</option>
  <option value="17">Leave Without Pay</option>
</select>
```

Optionally if you want to trigger onchange event also, you can use :

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

Comment: Great answer, this is way easier than looping through the options. And it's standards compliant: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-select-element.html#the-select-element. If there are browser incompatibilities (of course there are :) I'd be very interested to know what they are. That's the sort of thing you usually count on ppk for, but he stubbornly refuses to show up in my searches for this topic.

Comment: @Milan Maybe the cross browser issue is when *valueToSelect* does not exist in the Select Options, where browsers may behave differently (like 1.do not change current value, or 2.set value to null, or 3.force value to be that one anyway...)? I didn't try myself, just wondering.

Comment: And what about multiple selects? This doesn't seem to work in case of multiple options (at least in Chrome 25).

Comment: Important to note that this does not actually reflect the HTML `value=""` attribute. `<select>` doesn't support a value attribute and setting that in your HTML will do absolutely nothing. `value` here is a property provided by the DOM API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

Comment: As @ring0 pointed out, when valueToSelect does not exist, it inserts a blank entry in chrome. whereas IE and firefox retains the last selected value.

Comment: Note for IE : the <option> must have a value='valueToSelect' attribute.  You can not use the display text within the <option>..</option> as a valueToSelect

Comment: Side note - in chrome, a hidden field will not have it's value changed dynamically so it must be visible and/or display != none;

Comment: If you need the change event to be fired, you should also do:

`element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: Thank you. I needed to do with two values and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 153):

If you are using jQuery you can also do this:

```
$('#leaveCode').val('14');
```

This will select the `<option>` with the value of 14.

---

With plain Javascript, this can also be achieved with two [`Document` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#Methods):

- With [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), you can select an element based on a CSS selector:

  ```
  document.querySelector('#leaveCode').value = '14'
  ```
- Using the more established approach with [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), that will, as the name of the function implies, let you select an element based on its `id`:

  ```
  document.getElementById('leaveCode').value = '14'
  ```

You can run the below code snipped to see these methods and the jQuery function in action:

```js
const jQueryFunction = () => {
  
  $('#leaveCode').val('14'); 
  
}

const querySelectorFunction = () => {
  
  document.querySelector('#leaveCode').value = '14' 
  
}

const getElementByIdFunction = () => {
  
  document.getElementById('leaveCode').value='14' 
  
}
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode">
  <option value="10">Annual Leave</option>
  <option value="11">Medical Leave</option>
  <option value="14">Long Service</option>
  <option value="17">Leave Without Pay</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="$('#leaveCode').val('14');" onclick="jQueryFunction()" />
<input type="button" value="document.querySelector('#leaveCode').value = '14'" onclick="querySelectorFunction()" />
<input type="button" value="document.getElementById('leaveCode').value = '14'" onclick="getElementByIdFunction()" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This can also be used for multi-select; just pass an array of strings to the 'val' function instead of a single string.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16583001/88409

Comment: Is there a way to also trigger $('#leaveCode').on('change', function() by doing that?

Comment: $("#leaveCode").val("14").change();

Answer (score 32):

```
function setSelectValue (id, val) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
setSelectValue('leaveCode', 14);
```

Answer (score 24):

Not answering the question, but you can also select by index, where i is the index of the item you wish to select:

```
var formObj = document.getElementById('myForm');
formObj.leaveCode[i].selected = true;
```

You can also loop through the items to select by display value with a loop:

```
for (var i = 0, len < formObj.leaveCode.length; i < len; i++) 
    if (formObj.leaveCode[i].value == 'xxx') formObj.leaveCode[i].selected = true;
```

Comment: Shouldn't formObj.leaveCode[i].selected = true; be formObj.options[i].selected = true; ?

Answer (score 19):

## Short

This is size improvement of [William answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78960/860099)

```
leaveCode.value = '14';
```

```js
leaveCode.value = '14';
```

```html
<select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode">
  <option value="10">Annual Leave</option>
  <option value="11">Medical Leave</option>
  <option value="14">Long Service</option>
  <option value="17">Leave Without Pay</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this use a jquery selector or something? Or am I just slow this morning and one can simply call some_id.value in js?

Comment: this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions yes it turns out one can simply call `some_id.value` in browser JS instead of `document.getElementByID("some_id").value`, though you probably shouldn't. Discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325221/why-dont-we-just-use-element-ids-as-identifiers-in-javascript It looks like it's a very old feature that was kept for backward compatibility. It's very tempting to use it since it's so much briefer and prettier...

Answer (score 17):

I compared the different methods:

[Comparison of the different ways on how to set a value of a select with JS or jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/8sM7s/1/)

code:

```js
$(function() {
    var oldT = new Date().getTime();
     var element = document.getElementById('myId');
    element.value = 4;
    console.error(new Date().getTime() - oldT);

    oldT = new Date().getTime();
    $("#myId option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('value') == 4;
    }).attr('selected', true);
    console.error(new Date().getTime() - oldT);

    oldT = new Date().getTime();
    $("#myId").val("4");
    console.error(new Date().getTime() - oldT);
});
```

Output on a select with  ~4000 elements:

- 1 ms
- 58 ms
- 612 ms

With Firefox 10. Note: The only reason I did this test, was because jQuery performed super poorly on our list with ~2000 entries (they had longer texts between the options).
We had roughly 2 s delay after a val()

Note as well: I am setting value depending on the real value, not the text value.

Answer (score 13):

```
document.getElementById('leaveCode').value = '10';
```

That should set the selection to "Annual Leave"

Answer (score 13):

I tried the above JavaScript/jQuery-based solutions, such as:

```
$("#leaveCode").val("14");
```

and

```
var leaveCode = document.querySelector('#leaveCode');
leaveCode[i].selected = true;
```

in an AngularJS app, where there was a **required** <select> element.

None of them works, because the AngularJS form validation is not fired. Although the right option was selected (and is displayed in the form), the input remained invalid (**ng-pristine** and **ng-invalid** classes still present).

To force the AngularJS validation, call jQuery [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) after selecting an option:

```
$("#leaveCode").val("14").change();
```

and

```
var leaveCode = document.querySelector('#leaveCode');
leaveCode[i].selected = true;
$(leaveCode).change();
```

Comment: Why use jQuery for this when you can already do it with Angular? When using Angular itself, don't you have the ability to set the value, with built-in support for triggering the change (No idea, I use React, just found this post after a 5 second google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302062/angular-5-set-selected-value-of-html-select-element)? Because that would mean you don't have to hack around Angular with an additional ±30kb library "just for this" :)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way if you need to:
1) Click a button which defines select option
2) Go to another page, where select option is
3) Have that option value selected on another page

**1)** your button links (say, on home page)

```
<a onclick="location.href='contact.php?option=1';" style="cursor:pointer;">Sales</a>
<a onclick="location.href='contact.php?option=2';" style="cursor:pointer;">IT</a>
```

(where **contact.php** is your page with select options. Note the page url has ?option=1 or 2)

**2)** put this code on your second page (my case **contact.php**)

```
<?
if (isset($_GET['option']) && $_GET['option'] != "") {
$pg = $_GET['option'];              
} ?>
```

**3)** make the option value selected, depending on the button clicked

```
<select>
<option value="Sales" <? if ($pg == '1') { echo "selected"; } ?> >Sales</option>
<option value="IT" <? if ($pg == '2') { echo "selected"; } ?> >IT</option>
</select>
```

.. and so on.
So this is an easy way of passing the value to another page (with select option list) through GET in url. No forms, no IDs.. just 3 steps and it works perfect.

Answer (score 3):

```
function foo(value)
{
    var e = document.getElementById('leaveCode');
    if(e) e.value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be something along these lines:

```
function setValue(inVal){
var dl = document.getElementById('leaveCode');
var el =0;
for (var i=0; i<dl.options.length; i++){
  if (dl.options[i].value == inVal){
    el=i;
    break;
  }
}
dl.selectedIndex = el;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your form is named **form1**:

```
function selectValue(val)
{
  var lc = document.form1.leaveCode;
  for (i=0; i&lt;lc.length; i++)
  {
    if (lc.options[i].value == val)
    {
        lc.selectedIndex = i;
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a variable for the element's Id and make it a reusable function?

```
function SelectElement(selectElementId, valueToSelect)
{    
    var element = document.getElementById(selectElementId);
    element.value = valueToSelect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code mentioned here didn't worked for me!

**At last, this worked**

***window.addEventListener** is important, otherwise, your JS code will run before values are fetched in the Options*

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            // Selecting Element with ID - leaveCode  //
            var formObj = document.getElementById('leaveCode');

            // Setting option as selected
            let len;
            for (let i = 0, len = formObj.length; i < len; i++){
                if (formObj[i].value == '<value to show in Select>') 
                 formObj.options[i].selected = true;
            }
    });
```

Hope, this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You most likely want this:

```
$("._statusDDL").val('2');
```

OR

```
$('select').prop('selectedIndex', 3);
```

Comment: This is assuming the OP is using JQuery though

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle, Which is not, because even the title of the questions ends with `using JavaScript`.

Answer (score -3):

If using PHP you could try something like this:

```
$value = '11';
$first = '';
$second = '';
$third = '';
$fourth = '';

switch($value) {
            case '10' :
                $first = 'selected';
            break;
            case '11' :
                $second = 'selected';
            break;
            case '14' :
                $third = 'selected';
            break;
            case '17' :
                $fourth = 'selected';
            break;
        }

echo'
<select id="leaveCode" name="leaveCode">
  <option value="10" '. $first .'>Annual Leave</option>
  <option value="11" '. $second .'>Medical Leave</option>
  <option value="14" '. $third .'>Long Service</option>
  <option value="17" '. $fourth .'>Leave Without Pay</option>
</select>';
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript question, not a PHP/HTML one

Answer (score -7):

I'm afraid I'm unable to test this at the moment, but in the past, I believe I had to give each option tag an ID, and then I did something like:

```
document.getElementById("optionID").select();
```

If that doesn't work, maybe it'll get you closer to a solution :P

Comment: The [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionElement) does not have a `select()` method (it does not define any additional methods over the standard set on all HTML elements). However, you can set the `selected` property to true.