# Querying DB Continuously for Update - java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a query to fetch the name and id of companies. I am able to fetch all the companies but my issue is with the id of the companies. I have a combo box to display list of companies and another label which displays the id of the company selected in the combo box.

Here is my issue, when i change the selected company in the combo box, the label showing the id still remains displays the id of the initial company selected.  Is there a way that i could continuously query the database to update the id?

**PS**  I display companies in the combo box with reference no.

```
public AssignCompanies() {
    initComponents();
    conn = DBConnection.ConnectDB();

    FindCompanyID();
}

public void FindCompanyID() {
    String sql = "Select * from Company where ID = "+FindSelectedCompany.getSelectedItem();

    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()) {
            String getSelectedCompany = rs.getString("Reference Number");
            seats.setText(getSelectedCompany);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Continuously* query the database?  Why?  Why not just update the label when the combo box changes?  Doesn't the combo box (or at least an in-memory list) contain the value you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to query the database everytime a user changes the selection in combo box, you can do the following:

- Get ids and names of all the companies, and dynamically add `option` elements into combo box with `value` being `id` and `label` being `name` of the company
- Configure an `onchange` event on that combo box, [here's](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) an example
- Write a javscript function to update the value in another combo box in the `onchange` event configured in previous step ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490906/how-to-change-a-select-value-from-javascript) an example of how to update the value)