# Select Option Javascript doesn't trigger the website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have this thirs-part website, where if I select one country on the right

(as you can see in the video:
 https://i.gyazo.com/3a22aabb576f1e43040dae82204bb883.mp4 )

it changes shipping fees (in violet).

If instead, I use js ( from the chrome console for instance) to select one country using

```
 document.getElementById("order").value =  "IT";
```

it will select the country but the fees on the don't change. There is a way to let it works using javascript?

I have tried to also perform a click by

```
document.getElementById("order").click();
```

after selecting a value but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to post more code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your what you tried, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: this is a third part websites i have tried with the cose i have posted but nothing .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a <select> value from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490906/how-to-change-a-select-value-from-javascript)

Comment: @MartinZeitler i think it's a different problem

Comment: @Marià how shall this be any different? ever tried `.onchange()`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler i have tried all the codes in the other posts and it won't do what i need

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the onchange after changing the value - you can do that from the console or from a chrome extension

```js
document.getElementById("order").value = "IT";
document.getElementById("order").onchange();
```

```html
<select id="order" onchange="alert(this.value)">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="IT">Italy</option>
</select>
```

If the site has jQuery, use `$("#order").val("IT").change()`

Comment: the website is third-par i can't edit the html part i just want to trigger the change when i use the getlelementbyyd.value="IT";

Comment: You can do that without changing the site. `document.getElementById("order").value = "IT";
document.getElementById("order").onchange();` - the select has an onchange already

Comment: If the site has jQuery, use `$("#order").val("IT").change()`

Comment: i cannot use jquery unfrtunatly i have tryed whit the occhange() but the console gives me this error : Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onchange is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:50

Comment: if `document.getElementById("order").value = "IT";` works then it is very strange that it does not allow onchange

Comment: And I did not mean YOU should use jQuery, just call it if it is present in the site.

Comment: ok i have tried the jquery stuff and it works... the problem is i'm in a chorme extension so i can't use jquery as i know , while the onchange says that is not a function

Comment: Of course you can use jQuery if the page you are on has loaded and is using it. You can also load jQuery if it is not loaded by the page