# How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, select, selected

How to set the 'selected' (default) value for an HTML `<select>` element with JavaScript. Aka. currently option0 is 'selected', how to run a script to change it to display the value i want?

*this for example because that value is previously saved in a database, and i only want it updated if the user actually specifies to do so. But if i don't specify the value (by re-selecting the previous option), saving the 'edit' will overwrite the previous value with the 'default selected' value the `<select>` is loaded with.*

```
<select id="selector" name="selector">
  <option id="option0" value="0" selected=true >default </option>
  <option id="option1" value="1">option 1 </option>
  <option id="option1" value="2">option 2 </option>
  <option id="option1" value="3">option 3 </option>
  <option id="option1" value="4">option 4 </option>
</select>
```

**NOTE**: *Because i lack reputation to add my answer (below) to the general thread on this topic, here the solution i got to using javascript, to set an option to be the option displayed/selected in the selector. This can also be a <%= value %> from a database.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Use `value` property to set new selected value using JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById('selector').value="2";
```

```html
<select id="selector" name="selector">
  <option id="option0" value="0" selected=true >default </option>
  <option id="option1" value="1">option 1 </option>
  <option id="option1" value="2">option 2 </option>
  <option id="option1" value="3">option 3 </option>
  <option id="option1" value="4">option 4 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script> 
    let options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

    for(i=0; i<options.length; i++){
        if (options[i].value === "<%= or_some_string %>"){
            options[i].selected = true;
        }
    } 
</script>
```

We get all the options (this is an html collection) and iterate over it to check if any option is equal to the "String" or "<%=string_value_from_database%>". And set it's .selected to true.

**NOTE - MAYBE BETTER - DEFFO SHORTER:**  with help in the comments:

```
<script>
  let to_select = document.getElementById('selector');
  to_select.value = "<%= value %>";
</script>
```

Where to_select.value is either set to the value you want, or to a database value. Do note, you may or may not need the ".." around the value you set, depending on the setup of the `<select>` and how you stored your data.

Comment: There's no need for all of that. If the `select` does not have the `multiple` attribute, you do not need to set any other `option`'s `selected` property to false before setting another's to true. You also don't need to loop; just set the value of the `select` element to the value retrieved from the database, as noted in the answers to the question linked in the comment to the question.

Comment: See, that first thing is definitely something you need to know (i edited it out, from my answer), i tried it and it works in my case :) ... i will check the code you linked to as well.

Comment: Ok, i managed to make that code work, but i had to add ".." around my the database call to have it update in the html selector on screen correctly (otherwise it said the data from the database was 'undefined'; aka it treated it as some variable).

Comment: @HereticMonkey tnx for your time and attention, i'd give a rep if i could? ... anyways, i included the answer you linked to with the note that i ran into myself.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
document.getElementById("selector").selectedIndex = 3;
```

[original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490906/how-to-change-a-select-value-from-javascript)

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions. Instead, flag them as duplicates, giving the URL of the duplicate question (the "original" link in your answer).

Comment: @HereticMonkey See, i can't add my answer to these questions, because i lack the reputation to do so, but i don't see my answer as one of the answers given... while for me the answer i provide (see my name in the list of answers) is the one i needed. So seeing stackoverflow doesn't let me provide the answer, the only way for me to help somebody else is to do it like this...

Comment: @Arghore You can add your answer to the question I linked to. Anyone can; there is no lock on that question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey --- I see: Highly active question. Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity. ;) ... so i can't :(

Comment: @Arghore Argh; sorry, this is part of a bunch of changes Stack Overflow has been making. I don't see that message because I have more rep, so I didn't think it was locked like that :(. That's annoying...

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's ok i'll get the rep eventually :) tnx anyways for your understanding and your help.