# diffrent default and selected value in html select

Tags: html, jsp

I need different default and selected value for HTML `<select>` tag. It means that I need my `<form>` load with a selected `<option>`, then after pressing `<button type="reset">` button another option set to select tag, but how?

```
<select size="1" name="select1" >
    <option  value='1'> default value </option>
    <option selected="true" value="2">selected value</option>
</select>
```

onclick event for button doesn't works:

```
<button onclick="resetSearchPanel();" type="reset"> ...
```

java script function:

```
 function resetSearchPanel() {

  document.forms['submitSearch'].elements['select1'].value = "1";

}
```

above snippet works when the button type property setted as 'button' but it doesn't work when type set to reset!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reset button will reset all values back to default. Its `onclick` happens **before** the actual reset taking place, so any change you make there will be lost.

Since there is no "onafterclick" even, only way around if you must use reset button is using a timer:

```
function resetSearchPanel() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.forms['submitSearch'].elements['select1'].value = "1";
    }, 100);
}
```

This will change the selected value 0.1 seconds after clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks, It works. But is there any better solution? It seems dirty coding!!  I can't vote up because of my low reputation, thank You.

Comment: Clean coding would be using custom reset button but I understand you can't change the HTML.. ??

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of reset, just make the required value in the select tag as selected.

on Onclick() method of reset button, make sure that you write a function which does whatever you want to.

If you set the button type as `reset`, it will reset the whole of form data, so youe select tag will not be having the value you set it to. Remove `reset` tag, and it should be fine.

If its must for you to use type as "reset" then you have to use work arounds to make sure that  your code is executed after the form is reset, but that approach is strongly discouraged.

Comment: whats the function that you have written?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript Please refer to this link

Comment: What is submitSearch here? Have you verified that document.forms['submitSearch'].elements['select1'] is able to get your exact select tag?

Comment: YES! it is snippet, not full code. It works when type is button.

Comment: Whats the problem if you don't use reset type and just use button type?

Comment: I need reset button, it resets all inputs, it is my only input!

Comment: No other than setting a delay, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have given button `type='reset'` dont know why because type reset will clear the form data. So for your problem you need to give the button `type='button'`

```
<button onclick="resetSearchPanel();" type="button">
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I need reset button. I have several input in my form and I need reset all to default value after clicking reset.

Answer (score -1):

Select option you need on page load with JavaScript.

Comment: Because of our company framework limits, this solution can't implemented

Comment: @MohsenKashi - If there are limitations that restrict what solutions are acceptable to you, you should add them to the question.

Comment: @HottDogg it is our coding conversation