# Can't set multiple values in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to show selected values in select2-jquery component.

```
var select = $(".select2").select2({
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: "",
    width:'100%',
    data: z 
});
var selectedValues = $("#sourceValues").val().split(',');

$.each( selectedValues, function(k,v){
    $(".select2").select2('val',v);
})
```

Element `sourceValues` holds the value e.g : 2,4 
   And `z` is array of object that holds id and text as suggested. 
  I can see the `<options>` that is linked to the Select2 element but I am unable to show the selected values on the element. 
    Also, If I try to run the query on Chrome console it works , if I write something like ;

```
  $(".select2").select2('val',4)
```

Hence, the `<option>` with the id 4 is selected.

Comment: Have you tried to set the array directly: `$(".select2").select2('val', selectedValues);`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Update (Select2 4.0+)

Since version 4.0, you should use `.val(...)` followed by `trigger('change')` from jQuery.

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options

Up-to-date example:

```js
var selectedValues = $("#sourceValues").val().split(',');
$(".select2").val(selectedValues).trigger('change');

// $(".select2").val([1, 2]).trigger('change');
```

## Original answer (Select2 3.5.3)

http://select2.github.io/select2/#documentation

> **val**
>
> Attached to select - Multi-Valued - Array of the value attributes of the
>   options that should be selected. null for empty.

So:

```js
var selectedValues = $("#sourceValues").val().split(',');
$(".select2").select2('val',selectedValues);

// $(".select2").select2('val',[1, 2]);
```

Comment: this seems to be not working on multiple select or I am missing something.

Comment: For 4.0.2 `$('.select2').val(selectedValues);` seems to be working

Answer (score 42):

Select2 4.0 version in case someone needs:

```
var selectedValues = $("#sourceValues").val().split(',');
$(".select2").val(selectedValues).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I've been googling for more than an hour! :D

Comment: OMG I have been racking my brains trying every possible solution I could find with no avail and this did it, thanks so much man! It was all about `.val().split(',');`

Comment: This should be changed to the accepted answer as evidenced by the upvotes. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
var selectedValues = $("#sourceValues").val().split(',');
var $multiSelect = $(".select2").select2();
$multiSelect.val(selectedValues).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

for create dynamic array for example in a loop do like this:

```
 data=[]

    for(let input of inputs){

          *//key of dynamic build*
           if(typeof data[input.name]==='undefined'){
                data[input.name]=[]}
            data[input.name].push(input.value);
            console.log(data)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I find and a bit upgrade and use ŁukaszW.pl suggestion for [JavaScript/jQuery set values selection in a multiple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582901/javascript-jquery-set-values-selection-in-a-multiple-select) and you can use it as well:

in jQuery:

```
var values = ["Test", "Prof", "Off"]; // or to take values as array from other document element;
$("#strings").val(values);
$("#strings").trigger('change'); //trigger change for select2 to set values/styles
```

or in pure JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('strings');
var values = ["Test", "Prof", "Off"]; // or to take values as array from other document element;
for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
    element.options[i].selected = values.indexOf(element.options[i].value) >= 0;
}
var event = new Event('change'); 
var sel = document.getElementById("strings"); 
sel.dispatchEvent(event); //trigger change for select2 to set values/styles
```

jQuery does significant abstraction here.

and Save :)
Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

given:

1. select2 v4
2. "Options" gets a php script when drawing a page from the database

it is necessary that select2 is filled as in the database. by default, it renders like this: option value description

I solved the question like this:
from class "select2-searchable" i am incluted html atrrribute <data-reorder="1"> and <data-value="a,d,c"> (from php)

```
$('.select2-searchable').each(function(i, e) { //table, interation all elements
    $(e).select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
        width: 'resolve',
    });
    if ($(e).attr('data-reorder')) {
        $(e).on('select2:select', function(el) { //adding a new value to the end of the list
            $(this).append(el.params.data.element).trigger('change.select2');
        });
        if ($(e).attr('data-value')) { //sorting by values from the database
            $.each($(e).attr('data-value').split(','), function(j, k) {
                $(e).find('[value=' + k + ']').each(function(m, l) {
                    l.selected = true;
                    $(e).append(l).trigger('change');
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

example here (https://jsfiddle.net/M0rdent/q9gn305d/3/)