# How can I use jquery to populate a select2 Multiple select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So I have a select2 Multiple select box (dropdown) like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>

<select id="selector" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

How can I use jquery to make certain options selected?

Thanks

edit:

I've tried this:

```
$("#selector option[value='AL']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

I want to choose from values that are already in the dropdown. I don't want to add new values that aren't already there.

So I want certain values to already be selected.

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html  <where I got it from

Comment: you are using multiple selected box ?

Comment: Sorry, yes. A multiple selected box. I'll edit the question to reflect that

Comment: so you want some value has to be there in initial ??

Comment: yes - I'm not using this to add extra values to the list. I just want to add one that's already there

Comment: could you please provide snippet or fiddle

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905607/select2-cant-set-multiple-value

Comment: select2  gives you alll values selected in an array separated with comas so you can get the value of the input and split  it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array or you can split the value in back end after POST

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it is:

```
$('#IDOFSELECTBOX').val("").change();
```

My internet went down so couldn't update. thanks for help