# Select2 multiple select default selections not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

This is my html code

```
<select name="age_group[]" class="form-control age_group" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($age_groups as $group)
        <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->age_group_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And this is the JS

```
var selected = [1, 2, 3];
// initialize select2 for age group
$(".age_group").select2();
$(".age_group").select2('val', selected);
```

What I want to do is set default values as selected as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905607/select2-cant-set-multiple-value) post. But in my code above I am only getting the first element of the array as selected.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1cqme2kp/)

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33912045/6746555 try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this it will work:

`$(".age_group").val(selectedvalue).trigger("change");`

sample fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/891/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the value you need to select.

```
$('select').select2().select2('val', $('.select2 option:eq(1)').val());
```

OR

```
Split the values before Passing to the Select2();
var values = //split the string ;
$(".age_group").select2('val',values);
```

Hope this Helps you.

Comment: I have not tried your first option as the other answer worked but your second option is same as i was doing . `values` in my case is already an array.