# How to select multiple select based on values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html

```
<select name="availableon[]" class="form-control" multiple>
     <option value="pc">PC</option>
     <option value="iphone">iPhone</option>
     <option value="android">Android</option>
 </select>
```

And in my AJAX success function I have the value

```
availableon = 'pc,iphone'
```

Now I want to explode the `availableon` variable and select the multiple select based on value using javascript or jquery. How will I do that?

Comment: If you are looking for a pure js solution, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582901/javascript-jquery-set-values-selection-in-a-multiple-select/43255752#43255752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the data to an `array` and then set the value with the array

```js
var availableon = 'pc,iphone'

var dataarray = availableon.split(",");

$("select").val(dataarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="availableon[]" class="form-control" multiple>
     <option value="pc">PC</option>
     <option value="iphone">iPhone</option>
     <option value="android">Android</option>
 </select>
```