# How to set multiple selectedIndexes without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16582901/4284627), but my question is different because the other question uses `value` *and* jQuery, neither of which I want to use.

---

It's easier to explain with an example:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('sel');
const indexes = new Set([0, 2, 4]);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(select.options, (opt, i) => {
  opt.selected = indexes.has(i);
});
```

```html
<select id="sel" multiple size=5>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
  <option selected>four</option>
  <option>five</option>
</select>
```

Is this the most efficient way to set the selected options `one`, `three` and `five`? `select.selectedIndex` doesn't seem to accept an array, so this is the only way I can think to do it. Using a `Set` ought to be more efficient than looping through an array, each time using `.includes`.

Comment: `selectedOptions` contains a collection of the selected option elements, but it's read-only. I think what you've got may be the best way.

Comment: But in your example you're also unselecting the option number four.

Comment: I tried few things and using loops seemed about 0.1 ms or more, setting `select.innerHTML` about 0.05 ms, and setting them without loop `select.selectedIndex = 0; select[2].selected = true; select[4].selected = true` about 0.03 ms. Ha! the irony of the marked as duplicate being the most **in**efficient way to multi-select

Comment: Here is very a similar question about choosing multiple options by value (instead of index): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582901/javascript-jquery-set-values-selection-in-a-multiple-select/47086131

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop your indexes array and update the `options` matching the indexes.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('sel');
const indexes = [0, 2, 4];
// Clear the default selected
select.selectedIndex = -1;
// Select those indexes you want
for(var idx of indexes){
  select[idx].selected = true
}
```

```html
<select id="sel" multiple size=5>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
  <option selected>four</option>
  <option>five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh...clever. I didn't think about resetting `selectedIndex` first to clear the existing selections.

Comment: Wait... what the heck. `select[2]` returns the 3rd option? You don't even need to do `select.options[2]`?

Comment: Yes. According to the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/item