# Setting selected attribute for <select multiple> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple select like this one could be:

```
 <select multiple id="brand">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And I'm looking for a way to end up like:

```
 <select multiple id="brand">
  <option value="volvo" selected="selected">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" selected="selected">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" selected="selected">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I can't depend on external libraries and I can't make the .each function to work properly.
Besides I'm getting the original  dinamically set with many fields, and this will be set to this only in a particular case, but i can't figure out why this isn't working for me.
The closest approach i found is:

```
$("#brand").each(function(){$(this).attr("selected","selected");});
```

Can you please point me out where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Do you want all selected? If so, the jquery that you've posted wont work, because you are looking for the select tag, you must look up for the option tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582989/4378314

Comment: @MarsAndBack i've already checked before i posted that but didnt worked for me or i didn't know how. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the options, for instance with a `#brand > option` selector:

```js
$("#brand > option").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
});

console.log($("#brand").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="brand">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just the missing sintax I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in Vanilla Script you could use something like this

```
  document.querySelectorAll('#brand option').forEach((o)=>{
    o.selected = 'selected'
  })
```

If You need IE, be aware that for Each is not supported with node Lists. This should work inkl. IE

```
nodesArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#brand option"));
nodesArray.forEach(function (o) {
     o.selected = 'selected'
})
```

You wont see the changes in HTML Code, but the DOM Properties of the options will change. Hope this helps.

Comment: Besides the solution i really appreciate the support with IE backup.

Comment: I cant approve both answers, and Trinkot got just to what was in my mind. But your answer is really helpful and works too. I think it will help other users too