# How to set value in multiselect dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui-multiselect

I want to update p_fullname and put data into multiselect dropdownbox using below function:

```
function update_project_group(pg_id,pg_group_name,p_fullname){
        document.getElementById('pg_id').value=pg_id;
        document.getElementById('group_name').value=pg_group_name;
        document.getElementById('projectmember').value=p_fullname;

        var array = p_fullname;
        var dataarray=array.split(",");
        $("#projectmember").val(dataarray);
        $('#projectmember').multiselect( 'settings', { columns: 2}); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582901/javascript-jquery-set-values-selection-in-a-multiple-select).

Html

```
<select name='strings' id="strings" multiple style="width:100px;">
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
    <option value="Live">Live</option>
    <option value="Off">Off</option>
    <option value="On">On</option>
</select>
```

javaScript

```
var values="Test,Prof,Off";
$.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("#strings option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

And here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/McddQ/1/

Comment: There is <li> used as below comment

Comment: <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search"><ul style="column-count: 2; column-gap: 0px;"><li data-search-term="vimal" class=""><label for="ms-opt-1" class=""><input type="checkbox" title="
                                                        Vimal" id="ms-opt-1" value="M_05022019175949063663">
                                                        Vimal</label></li>