# Cannot set multiple value of bootstrap select from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

So I have this string: `93, 94` which are the references of the values of a select.

I'm trying to set these values using:

```
let values = "93, 94";
$('#property-categories').selectpicker('val', values);
```

but not working, none of the value is selected in the `select` control.

If I write: `$('#property-categories').selectpicker('val', [93,94]);`

works, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a comma delimited string in to an array, which is the type required here, use `split()`.

```
let values = "93, 94";
$('#property-categories').selectpicker('val', values.split(', '));
```

Comment: please test your code before posting.[link](http://jsfiddle.net/2ascjdyr/)

Comment: @jishansiddique It already works. https://jsfiddle.net/g4y02nfa/

Comment: Because you used a very outdated version of selectpicker, for some reason

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan could I ask a little more help? The issue happen again if I provide non numerical values, eg: `modern,historic,seaside,minimalist`, could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Text values work too. The difference with that string is that you're using just `,` to delimit the string instead of `, ` (note the trailing space after the comma). Fix that and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/rgkmwd9v/.

Comment: Old but gold .... this worked for me: $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', data.colors.split(',')); ...... thanks dude :b

Answer (score 1):

Please check this one for simple select control

```
var values="93,94";
$.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("#strings option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

> For selectpicker you need to set below code

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['93','94']);
```

Check here working demo - > [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/t0xicCode/96ntuxnz/)

Comment: Your first example won't update the selectpicker UI and the second calls `selectpicker()` twice for no reason.

Comment: Also please don't [plagiarise other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582989/519413)

Comment: Yes, I understood the problem thanks for sharing your response.