# Select dropdown form by URL

Tags: html, forms, url, select, submit

I feel kind of dumb asking this question… I think the sollution could be quite simple.

On this page: http://crossfit-frauenfeld.com/preise/anmelden/ there's a form. And [on the subpage](http://crossfit-frauenfeld.com/preise/) I'm linking to the form. What I want to do is, choosing one of the «Betreff»-Select-Dropbdown by URL. Is this possible anyhow? I hope you can understand, what I mean… ;-)

Thanks a lot in adavance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Javascript to accomplish what you want. Basically when you click one of the links in your subpage, you want to call a Javascript function that changes which value in your dropdown is selected.

Here's an example that I think is relevant to your problem:

[How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript)

Comment: And how do I say the script to choose a different select element with the link only? Is this possible with your solution? Maybe I'm just to stupid to get it.

Comment: @michael `<option value="17">Leave Without Pay</option>`
You can set a value to each of your options like they do in the example. So this option "Leave Without Pay" would have to value 17. And in your Javascript function, you would set the selected value to value 17.