# HTML select option showing "wrong" value

Tags: javascript, html

In express I am rendering a handlebar template populating a form with values.

To populate my select options I set the "value" property of my select node like so:

```
<select class="inputField" name="gender" value="female">
    <option value="male">Männlich</option>
    <option value="female">Weiblich</option>
</select>
```

Visually the male option is selected though. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

EDIT 1:

I am aware of the selected property, but it makes stuff more complicated when templating, so I'd rather pass down the selected value.

But to be more precise on my original question:

why does this work then:

```
var genderEl = document.getElementById('genderSelect');
    genderEl.value = "female";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `select`s work.  You need to use the `selected` attribute on an `option`, like this:

```
<select class="inputField" name="gender">
    <option value="male">Männlich</option>
    <option value="female" selected="1">Weiblich</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript

Comment: I assumed it does, since programatically setting the value of the "select"-node with javascript results working

Comment: @MaxBumaye Well, HTML and JavaScript don't always work the same way. :)

Comment: Okay, I see the javascript part el.value = 'female' does'nt affect the property of the select field. Don't get me wrong, but is'nt the DOM in someway responsible for showing evidence of the Result?

Comment: @MaxBumaye the DOM itself doesn't do much of anything; it has to be acted on by JavaScript, which is frustratingly inconsistent. Most modern browsers will update the DOM correctly, but there are still lots of surprises out there.

Comment: So it's just a lack of consistency if I understand correctly?

Comment: @MaxBumaye you got it.

Comment: Thanks :) This is what I needed

Answer (score 3):

the correct way to pre-select an option in a select input is:

```
<select class="inputField" name="gender">
    <option value="male">Männlich</option>
    <option value="female" selected>Weiblich</option>
</select>
```

if you are using xhtml or html4, you should change **selected** for **selected="selected"**

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this work then: `var genderEl = document.getElementById('genderSelect'); genderEl.value = "female";`

Simply because DOM uses different properties ;-)

To answer your original question: [There is no `value` attribute for selects in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select), but [there is one in DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement). So you have to stick with the `selected` attribute, if you want a pure HTML solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
<select class="inputField" name="gender">
    <option value="male">Männlich</option>
    <option value="female" selected>Weiblich</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select a option use:

```
<option value="female" selected="selected">Weiblich</option>
```

[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element)