# Save new click change with jQuery on RELOAD (new page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a dropdown with a html value change result, so after every click i get the new html value:

```
$("#list li a").on('click',function(){
 var val=$(this).html();
 $("#selector").html(val);
});
```

Simple enough to understand. What I'm trying to do is in the new reload, the html (val) stays on the new load. How can one do this?

I was thinking of HTML5: localStorage but really not sure if this is right?

```
localStorage.setItem(currentlist, $('#selector').val());

    window.onload = function() {
        var name = localStorage.getItem(currentlist);
    }
```

Not sure if Im doing this right or missing something. But this is where I'm at. Is this the right way to go...or do some cookie state?

Comment: what is `currentlist` ? is it a string?

Comment: Localstorage is definetly One way to Do this, but is it working or Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programatically set the value of a select box element using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript)

Comment: The first parameter needs to be a string that doesn't change (*I'm assuming you might be using an array*), such as: `localStorage.setItem("currentlist", $('#selector').val())`.

Comment: @Cory This question is not a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Comment: If you simply want to access the value when the page is reload, I would suggest using sessionStorage instead localstorage. If you want persistent beyond the life of the session, you should use localStorage or a database.

Comment: @Krishna `currentlist` is just a var i was making for the #selector result val

Comment: `localStorage` has the ability to store with keys as strings, integers or even arrays. So that shouldn't matter, as long as you're using the same key to set and get. Although, using strings as key is the norm.

Comment: @Cory I changed the title...setting value is fine... its keeping it on reload...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xsanffhd/1/)

```
$("#list li a").on('click',function(){
    var val = $(this).html();
    $("#selector").html(val);
    localStorage.setItem("currentlist", val); //add to localStorage
});
```

and in your `onload`

```
var name = localStorage.getItem("currentlist"); //get from localStorage
$("#selector").html(name); //assign here
```

Comment: what do you mean by: `(name)` would it not be `(val)`? Because its a multiple list.

Comment: `(name)` is just the variable you're actually assigning the value to, doesn't matter what you name it.

Comment: @Riskbreaker - I'm using the same variable name from the question in order to not confuse you. Ideally, you could use a better name and use the same for setting inside.

Comment: on a side note, don't use variable names like `val`, `name`, `html` etc. Be more specific like `storedList` or `selectedHtml`.

Comment: @Krishna great Let me try this method as far as `(name)`, i guess I can use that or change it to `(list)` instead of `(val)`...thanks!

Comment: @Krishna so all I need to add is something like so:  `localStorage.setItem("currentlist", name);` changed val to name. And then add the Windows onLoad statement?

Comment: @Riskbreaker - the `setItem` needs to be in the click event and the variable names should match(in your case `val`). Inside your `onload` function, write the 2 lines in the bottom portion of my answer.

Comment: @Krishna Roger that. One last question - where does one place the `onload`  in my master js file....at end? start? does it matter?

Comment: Here is the demo.. https://jsfiddle.net/xsanffhd/1/ Use `$(document).ready` instead. So that you won't wait for other resources to load.