# As I create a select menu, which is in the first position with the current url:

Tags: php, jquery, html

As I create a select menu, which is in the first position with the current URL, changing the `selected` of `option`:

```
<select >
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste1" selected>test1</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste2">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste3">YouTube</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste4">test 4</option>
</select>
```

Example browser URL `http://www.test.test.4`:

```
<select >
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste4" selected>test 4</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste1/">test1</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste2">Google</option>
  <option value="http://www.test.com/teste3">YouTube</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is very unclear as it stands. Please make a better attempt at explaining what you need. Do you need the `option` whose `value` attribute has the URL of the current page to always be selected by default? I've removed tags that are not relevant to the question.

Comment: The "selected" must be selected in the option with the url corrent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand, you include this code on all of this pages and you want to change selected option ?

Maybe you can do it with JS with the onload event on your body (on each pages).

Example for the http://www.test.com/teste2 body:

[How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript)

```
<body onload="selectElement('http://www.test.com/teste2')">
```

Comment: Please make an example, because they are looking understand

Comment: Edited this morning, waiting your feedback if it don't correspond to your problem.