# Function jQuery Menu select url browser

Tags: jquery

How do I create a code `window.location.href` to give exact with the `value` of the `<option` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          $('select').find('option[value=window.location.href]').attr('selected','selected');
        });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value="http://www.test.com/page0">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page1">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page2">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page3">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page4">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page5">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page6">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page7">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page8">United States dollar (USD)</option>
</select>
```

Example browser url: http://www.test.com/page8 to be selected:

```
<select>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page8" selected="selected" >United States dollar (USD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page0">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page1">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page2">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page3">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page4">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page5">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page6">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page7">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 'option[value="'+window.location.href+'"]'  try this, currently you are just using window.location.href string instead of its value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [As I create a select menu, which is in the first position with the current url:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067428/as-i-create-a-select-menu-which-is-in-the-first-position-with-the-current-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.href` is a javascript property of the location object, so it needs to be concatenated to the value string so that its value is applied within the string and the value is better to be quoted:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('select').find('option[value="'+ window.location.href+'"]')
              .attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Example:

```js
var locationHrefMock = "http://www.test.com/page5" ;
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('select').find('option[value="'+ locationHrefMock +'"]')
              .attr('selected','selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value="http://www.test.com/page0">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page1">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page2">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page3">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page4">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page5">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page6">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page7">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
<option value="http://www.test.com/page8">United States dollar (USD)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       var url = $('select').attr('selected','selected').val();
       alert(url);

    });
    </script>

    <select>
       <option value="http://www.test.com/page0">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
    <option value="http://www.test.com/page1">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
    <option value="http://www.test.com/page2">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
    <option value="http://www.test.com/page3">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
    <option value="http://www.test.com/page4">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
    <option value="http://www.test.com/page5">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
    <option value="http://www.test.com/page6">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
    <option value="http://www.test.com/page7">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
    <option value="http://www.test.com/page8" selected="selected">United States dollar (USD)</option>
    </select>
```