# Angular 5 Set selected value of HTML Select Element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```html
<select name="manager" id="manager" [(ngModel)]="property.manager" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeManager($event)" required>
  <option disabled value="">Select Manager</option>
  <option *ngFor="let manager of managers" [ngValue]="manager" [selected]="manager?.name === 'Subhan Ahmed'">
    {{manager?.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

What I need is when the view is initialised, I need to set the value of the select where `manager?.name == property.manager.name` (which is loaded from db on on another event). I've tried to place a default text `Subhan Ahmed` to select the default value but its not working.

Managers are loaded at the start, I load them from Firestore and assign them to a variable `managers: Observable<Manager>;` during `subscribe()`, while `property.manager`is loaded after another input's change event.

Am i missing something?

Comment: You say "which is loaded from db on on another event". What it loaded from the db? I assume it is the list of managers. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I load Managers from Firestore and assign them to a local variable `managers: Observable<Manager>;` in subscribe().

Comment: `property.manager` is loaded after a change event on an  input. managers are loaded at the start.

Comment: Please note that `property.manager` is bound to the dropdown list with `[(ngModel)]`. So, it is set by the selected item in the list. It cannot be bound to another input element at the same time.

Comment: Exactly, i just want to change the selected value equal to the manager that is loaded later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select an item of the dropdown list by setting the value of  `property.manager`. Assuming that `selectedName` is the name of the `Manager` item that you want to select, you can do this:

```
// Case sensitive
this.property.manager = this.managers.find(m => m.name === this.selectedName);

// Case insensitive
let selectedNameUp = this.selectedName.toUpperCase();
this.property.manager = this.managers.find(m => m.name.toUpperCase() === selectedNameUp);
```

---

Here are the relevant parts of the markup and code. See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3j7heg) for a demo.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="manager" [(ngModel)]="property.manager" class="form-control" required>
  <option disabled [ngValue]="undefined">Select Manager</option>
  <option *ngFor="let manager of managers" [ngValue]="manager">{{manager.name}}</option>
</select>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedName" (ngModelChange)="onNameChange($event)">
```

**Code:**

```
selectedName: string;

property = {
  ref_no: '',
  address: '',
  manager: undefined
};

managers = [
  { "company": "Test Company", "name": "John Doe", "id": "3oE37Fo2QxGHw52W7UHI" }, 
  { "company": "Another Company", "name": "John Brown", "id": "LRF8xAi48rRuWu0KZex3" }, 
  { "company": "XYZ", "name": "Subhan Ahmed", "id": "TqOQHbdwJdwgwD8Oej8v" }
];

onNameChange($event) {
  let selectedNameUp = this.selectedName.toUpperCase();
  this.property.manager = this.managers.find(m => m.name.toUpperCase() === selectedNameUp);
}
```

Comment: Yes It does have an ID generated by Firestore which I snapshot along with the data.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-coraqv Have a look at this scenario. Type a name  in input and hit tab. The select box should show you the selected value.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-coraqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Have a look now.

Comment: I updated my answer, and included the stackblitz adapted from yours.

Comment: No, In my scenario, its not working. I'll update the stackblitz with more code. I'm just missing something I recon. Your answer was really helpful by the way. I'll accept it as an answer as I get things working so that others can use a correct answer for future references. Thanks

Comment: Your solution works. It was some issue with how I implemented it in my scenario. Thanks you.