# How to fetch <select> element user input value from webview and set value on it automatically

Tags: javascript, android, webview, jsoup

After load the url in webview, it calls a javascript function at onPagefinished() method. it will open another webpage. In that webpage, there are three select elements like, select id="select1", select id="select2", select id="select3"

```
<select id="select1" tabindex="1"><option>...</option><option>...</option></select> 
<select id="select2"><option>...</option><option>...</option></select> 
<select id="select3"><option>...</option><option>...</option></select>
```

the values of the rest two select elements depend on the value of one and two select elements accordingly (onChange()).

Now what I want to do that when a user chooses the items of these three select elements for the first time, it will be saved in shared preference. After than when the user opens it the second time the saved value will be set automatically on that select elements.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you shouldn't use webviews unless there is no other way to do what you want.
take a look at this presentation [here](https://martinfowler.com/articles/multiMobile/)

about shared preferences, you can check for shared preferences when the application starts. if it's null that means that the user started the application for the first time. 
if it has a value (not equal to null). it means that it's not the first time for the user to open the app.

if you need more clarifications, let me know in the comments!

Comment: I know the process of shared preferences. My main problem is fetching the value of  user-selected item and set this value on the second time at the same place.

Comment: does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I have no control on this website.

Comment: your welcome. if there is no way to make an API request to change the select value. I don't think there would be a way to do it. I will keep looking.