# How to set an option from Dropdownlist with VBScript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, vbscript

My goal is super simple, I just want to fill a webpage using .vbs and
I did almost all, only remains the dropdown list

I used:

`Document.All.Item("CamposTrat[0]").Value = "FINALIZADO"`
and `Document.All.Item("CamposTrat[0]").SelectedIndex = 1` but neither worked.

The `.SelectedIndex = 1` almost worked, it "selected" the Option "FINALIZADO" with blue selection [(exemple & html code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRHco.png), but don't setted "FINALIZADO" as the 'value' on screen. It felt like that was missing to press "Enter" to confirm.

I just wanna put "FINALIZADO" without click or use `"SendKeys{"FINALIZADO"}"`. I wanna a beautiful code :D

Ps: I dont know much about java/vbscript. I don't know yet how to configure those types of codes. If someone can send the "full" code, it will help a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript

Comment: Unfortunately no. My dropdown has no "id", only "name"

Comment: So use that instead of the id? Or assign an id.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I do it :'(    I would appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 months later I had reached the beautiful code kkk:

```
Dim sh
Dim WS
Dim IE
Dim Produto
Dim Index
Dim Motivo
Dim Obs

Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For Each wnd In sh.Windows
   If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      Set IE = wnd
      Exit For
   End If
Next

With IE.Document.All
   If .Item("CamposProtocolo[8].Descricao").Value = "Plano de voz" or .Item("CamposProtocolo[8].Descricao").Value = "Após Horário Atendimento" Then
      Produto = "MÓVEL"
   Else
      Produto = .Item("CamposProtocolo[8].Descricao").Value
   End if

   If .Item("CamposProtocolo[7].Descricao").Value = "Cancelamento Total" or .Item("CamposProtocolo[7].Descricao").Value = "Cancelamento Parcial" Then
      Index  = 20
      Motivo = "OI CONTA TOTAL / OI TOTAL"
      Obs    = "Móvel e Oi Total cancelados - aguardando conclusão da OS." & Chr(13) & "- Sem acesso a cancelamento/migração R2 -"
   Else
      Index  = 26
      Motivo = "STATUS SUSPENSO"
      Obs    = "Sem acesso a " & Chr(13) & "- Nenhuma alteração realizada -"
   End if
End With

If MsgBox(" Finalizado? ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Powered by Alexan") = vbYes Then
   With IE.Document.All
      .Item("CamposTrat[0]").SelectedIndex          = 1
      .Item("select2-28796-container").InnerText    = "FINALIZADO"
      .Item("CamposTrat[1]").SelectedIndex          = 23
      .Item("select2-28797-container").InnerText    = "SOLICITAÇÃO ATENDIDA"
      .Item("CamposTrat[2]").Value                  = Produto
      .Item("CamposTrat[3]").Value                  = "BO RETENÇÃO EMPRESARIAL"
      .Item("CamposTrat[4]").Value                  = "CANCELADO"
      .Item("CamposTrat[5]").Value                  = .Item("CamposProtocolo[1].Descricao").Value
      .Item("CamposTrat[6]").Value                  = "0"
      .Item("CamposTrat[7]").Value                  = "0"
      .Item("CamposTrat[8]").Value                  = "-"
      .Item("CamposTrat[9]").Value                  = .Item("CamposProtocolo[14].Descricao").Value
      .Item("CamposTrat[10]").Value                 = "00.000.000/0000-00"
      .Item("CamposTrat[11]").Value                 = .Item("CamposProtocolo[1].Descricao").Value
      .Item("CamposTrat[12]").Value                 = "1"
      .Item("CamposTrat[13]").SelectedIndex         = 1
      .Item("select2-28809-container").InnerText    = "NÃO"
      .Item("Status").SelectedIndex                 = 2
      .Item("select2-Status-container").InnerText   = "Finalizado"
      .Item("Observacao").Value                     = "Protocolo perfilado com sucesso!"
   End With

   IE.Visible = True
   WS.AppActivate "Tratar Protocolos - Internet Explorer"
   IE.Document.All.Item("Observacao").Focus
   WS.SendKeys "^{a}"

ElseIf MsgBox("  Pendente?   ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Powered by Alexan") = vbYes Then
   With IE.Document.All
      .Item("CamposTrat[0]").SelectedIndex          = 4
      .Item("select2-28796-container").InnerText    = "PENDENTE"
      .Item("CamposTrat[1]").SelectedIndex          = Index
      .Item("select2-28797-container").InnerText    = Motivo
      .Item("CamposTrat[2]").Value                  = "FIXO + BL"
      .Item("CamposTrat[3]").Value                  = "BO RETENÇÃO EMPRESARIAL"
      .Item("CamposTrat[4]").Value                  = "DESMEMBRADO"
      .Item("CamposTrat[5]").Value                  = .Item("CamposProtocolo[1].Descricao").Value
      .Item("CamposTrat[6]").Value                  = "0"
      .Item("CamposTrat[7]").Value                  = "0"
      .Item("CamposTrat[8]").Value                  = "-"
      .Item("CamposTrat[9]").Value                  = .Item("CamposProtocolo[14].Descricao").Value
      .Item("CamposTrat[10]").Value                 = "00.000.000/0000-00"
      .Item("CamposTrat[11]").Value                 = .Item("CamposProtocolo[1].Descricao").Value
      .Item("CamposTrat[12]").Value                 = "0"
      .Item("CamposTrat[13]").SelectedIndex         = 1
      .Item("select2-28809-container").InnerText    = "NÃO"
      .Item("Status").SelectedIndex                 = 4
      .Item("select2-Status-container").InnerText   = "Pendente"
      .Item("Observacao").Value                     = Obs
   End With

   WS.AppActivate "Tratar Protocolos - Internet Explorer"
   IE.Document.All.Item("Observacao").Focus
   WS.SendKeys "{UP}"
   WS.SendKeys "{END}"
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

> ```
> IE.Document.All.Item("select2-37536-container").InnerText = "FINALIZADO"  
> IE.Document.All.Item("CamposTrat[0]").SelectedIndex = 1
> ```