# Prepopulate dropdown with query script - Javascript Shareflex

Tags: javascript, java, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a dropdown with 4 options. I want these options to be prepopulated depending on value that is selected from a different field. The different field is a "countries" field.

If country "A" or country "b" is selected, I want the dropdown to populate option 1.
If a different country, populate option 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- Find which event is fired when a user change the first dropdown value
- Register a function to this event
- In this function, detect what is the new input from the first dropdown. Check it, and change the value of the second dropdown depending on this check ([How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript) could be useful for the implementation)

If you have issue trying to do it, do not hesitate to ask :)